# MySQL: UNIQUE keys

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird issue, well, weird in my eyes anyway.
I've got a database with ID, username, email, password etc...
The ID is the Primary key, and both the username and email have the UNIQUE key assigned.

Now the strange thing is, when I submit, lets say the following values;

```
username: ActionHank
email: ah@ah.com
```

it is added.

Now when I try adding the same values again, I get an error that it is not allowed since it would be a duplicate entry. This works great.
But, when I put in the following next;

```
username: ActionHank2
email: ah@ah.com
```

It just adds it again, so 2 users have the same e-mail address while I've given the email row the UNIQUE key. I could also just change the e-mail address instead of the username and it will be added. So somehow the MySQL only registers one of the UNIQUE keys or something, I'm confused.

Could someone help me on this matter? Thanks

Edit: I've used phpMyAdmin to create the table and exported it to SQL, here's how the create table looks:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_registered` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip_address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`,`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=54 ;
```

So I think it has a composite as Michael and Kingkero suggested. How can I solve this within phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Are you sure that each row itself has a UNIQUE constraint and it doesn't apply to both together?

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname` for this table. You maybe have a composite `UNIQUE` on those columns rather than individual `UNIQUE` indices.

Comment: I'll edit the post. :)

Comment: If you want each of the two fields to be unique you'll have to split the unique key to 2 unique keys. Your current unique key works as expected, it ensures you have a unique combination of username-email pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined the combination of `username` and `email` to be unique.  If you want each to be unique, you need to define separate unique constraints:

```
create table . . .  
    unique username,
    unique email
)
```

Or, because these are single columns, you can just do:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_registered` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip_address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=54 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
```